# Custom Data Labels in Numbers Chart?

Tags: numbers

I have 3 columns of data that I'm using for a scatterplot.  X variable, Y variable, and Year.  I have the chart working properly for the data but cannot find anyway of labeling each point with the corresponding year.

Am I just being thick here?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different!

I hope I am wrong but I don't think the answer for Numbers has changed ("in general, there is no practical way of doing it outside text boxes") since [this question and its answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245213/how-i-label-scatter-plot-points-in-numbers) were posted a few years ago.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sorry that post didn't turn up in my search.